# Get all the users of a channel in Telegram using telethon library

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I have tried to get all the users from a channel using telethon builtin method (get_participants).

def all_participants():

```
client = TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

all_participants = []
participants = client.get_participants(username)

all_participants.extend(participants.users)
print(all_participants)
```

Comment: I get error as : telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.ChatAdminRequiredError: Chat admin privileges are required to do that in the specified chat

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is self-explanatory. Only admins of a Telegram channel can view the members, and you're not an admin of that channel.

Comment: I know what the error states. But needed to know if there is any chance to change the admin rights and then view the users.

Comment: Don't you think such a "chance" would be a serious security issue!?